# ROS2 serial driver with ROS message subscription

Tags: ros2, python, serial, rclpy, spin

I need to set up a ROS2 python serial device driver that also subscribes to a ROS message.  For serial drivers the only publish messages I set up the serial input in a select call like this. Here, the `va500.serial_handler(line)` is a method called after the select when serial data arrives.  It deals with the serial data, and then publishes a message.

```
 def main(args = None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    va500 = va500Driver()
    while True:
        try:
            rfds, wfds, efds = select.select([va500.comm.fileno()], [], [], 1.)
            if rfds.__len__() > 0 and rfds[0] == va500.comm.fileno():
                line = va500.comm.readline()
                va500.serial_handler(line)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Received shutdown command.')
            exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

For nodes that just publish and subscribe to ROS messages we have it set up like this.  These will sit in the `.spin()` and handle ros events as they happen using message callbacks defined elsewhere.

```
def main(args = None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    driver = ActuatorDriver()
    rclpy.spin(driver)
    driver.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd like to do both of these, but if I use the `.spin()` to handle the ros message callbacks I can't also set up the select to sit on the serial port.  I'm guessing the `MultiThreadedExecutor` is the answer, but maybe I'm missing something.